# How to hide Rows In GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have came across the we and check different web pages but I didnt find the one I was looking for. I have a gridview and all I want is to hide one of the rows based on the value in the cell.

What I need to happen is something like in the logic of this :

```
if (row = "someValue")
{
row.Visible = false;
}
```

for the record, I have tried this but no luck:

```
        protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string oRoleName = row.Field<string> ("SVal");
        if (oRoleName.Equals ("someValue")) {
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

It is not base weather the row is the first the 2nd or third (like: e.row[1], e.row[2], etc.) I need to filter the data base on the value in the row. Can anyone teach me how could this be done ?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: try this Implement RowDataBound, check for type DataRow and your value; if matches up e.Row.Visible = false;

Comment: jquery or javascript can do it with front end , in back end gridview event can do the same thing. by the way I didnt have a PC now ,let me know I will make a sample code if you still didnt get the example after 9 hours.

Comment: As much as possible I need to do this in c# alone sir, and not in js, json jquery etc.

Comment: Sir @techspider can you expound on this please ?

Answer (score 1):

In a RowDataBound event add something along the lines of this logic

```
if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text == "foo") {
e.Row.Visible = false;
}
```

EDIT:

If youre looking to check the value of each row as its entered (unless im understanding incorrectly, you should probably expand on your question a bit.)
Then you may want to use the event "CellValueChanged"
Check to see if the cell is null beforehand and then do the check for your value and apply logic accordingly below that.

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null) { 
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() == "foo")
        {
            // do your stuff here.
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is cell[5] sir, It must not be specific in the number of the cell but rather in the value of the cell because the row I'm looking for in the gridview changes its cell number value everytime since everytime, users are adding rows.

Comment: Apologies if I made you misunderstood. What I'm trying to say sir is that the cell number is changing because there are entries being added therefore, If say "adam" is currently in the grid and I save an entry say "aam" if the current cell number od 'adam' is 3 then it would be 4 if 'aam' is added. so the number of cell doesnt really matter. and for the record the cell value is not editable so cant use "CellValueChanged"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get the value of the column within the `GridViewRow`. You are on the right track. In `RowDataBound`, find the column you are after. Then check its value.

Here is an example. Use `FindControl()` to get the control in the specified column for the current row. If the control in that column is a `Label`, check the text of the label to see if it is the value you want hidden. If so, hide the row.

```
protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         Label lbl = e.Row.FindControl("MyLabel");
         if (lbl.Text == "MyValue")
         {
             e.Row.Visible = false;
         }
    }
}
```